JSON convert to tables in oracle sql using PLSQL
'''' {
"general":{
"product_key":"501088",
"group_subtype_id":1,
"group_subtype_name":"Wheel Speed Sensor",
"variant_id":6,
"variant_name":"DF22",
"rb_customer_id":287383
},
"partnumbers":[
{
"partnumber":"F04FD009BD",
"pn_type":"Series OEM",
"mat_status":"00 - planned",
"properties":[
{
"property_id":4,
"property_name":"ASIC P/N",
"value_id":38,
"value":"8905502648"
},
{
"property_id":5,
"property_name":"ASIC type",
"value_id":56,
"value":"TLE4942"
},
{
"property_id":6,
"property_name":"Axle",
"value_id":62,
"value":"Front / Rear Right"
},
{
"property_id":7,
"property_name":"Base Type - Development P/N",
"value_id":72,
"value":"ffffffffffffffffffffffffffff"
},
{
"property_id":8,
"property_name":"Base Type - Released P/N",
"value_id":73,
"value":"sssssssssssssssssssssss"
},
{
"property_id":9,
"property_name":"Bracket assembly @ Bosch",
"value_id":null,
"value":null
},
{
"property_id":10,
"property_name":"Bulk cable P/N",
"value_id":84,
"value":"5597299011"
},
{
"property_id":11,
"property_name":"Cable assembly P/N1",
"value_id":null,
"value":null
},
{
"property_id":12,
"property_name":"Cable assembly P/N2",
"value_id":null,
"value":null
},
{
"property_id":13,
"property_name":"Cable assembly P/N3",
"value_id":null,
"value":null
},
{
"property_id":14,
"property_name":"Cable Length in mm",
"value_id":null,
"value":null
},
{
"property_id":15,
"property_name":"Cable/Connector Outlet in Deg",
"value_id":null,
"value":null
},
{
"property_id":16,
"property_name":"Character",
"value_id":null,
"value":null
},
{
"property_id":17,
"property_name":"Clip assembly @ Bosch",
"value_id":null,
"value":null
},
{
"property_id":18,
"property_name":"Connector P/N",
"value_id":null,
"value":null
},
{
"property_id":19,
"property_name":"Connector Type",
"value_id":null,
"value":null
},
{
"property_id":20,
"property_name":"Development P/N",
"value_id":null,
"value":null
},
{
"property_id":21,
"property_name":"Function Dimension",
"value_id":null,
"value":null
},
{
"property_id":22,
"property_name":"IC Angle in Deg",
"value_id":null,
"value":null
},
{
"property_id":23,
"property_name":"Marking",
"value_id":null,
"value":null
},
{
"property_id":24,
"property_name":"Offer drawing",
"value_id":null,
"value":null
},
{
"property_id":25,
"property_name":"O-ring P/N",
"value_id":null,
"value":null
},
{
"property_id":26,
"property_name":"Pitch",
"value_id":null,
"value":null
},
{
"property_id":27,
"property_name":"Project category",
"value_id":167,
"value":"New project"
},
{
"property_id":28,
"property_name":"Protocol",
"value_id":172,
"value":"s"
},
{
"property_id":29,
"property_name":"Reading Dimension",
"value_id":null,
"value":null
},
{
"property_id":30,
"property_name":"Reading type",
"value_id":180,
"value":"Bottom Read"
},
{
"property_id":31,
"property_name":"Recommended Installation Bore",
"value_id":null,
"value":null
},
{
"property_id":32,
"property_name":"Target wheel",
"value_id":193,
"value":"Multipole encoder"
},
{
"property_id":33,
"property_name":"Used punch-grid / holder",
"value_id":null,
"value":null
}
]
}
],
"document_numbers":[
{
"document_number":"1234569871",
"document_version":"05",
"document_type":"TCD"
},
{
"document_number":"0123456789",
"document_version":"01",
"document_type":"TCD"
},
{
"document_number":"1234569870",
"document_version":"05",
"document_type":"TCD"
},
{
"document_number":"1234567890",
"document_version":"01",
"document_type":"TCD"
}
],
"target_markets":[
{
"country_name":"Belize",
"iso_code":"BZ"
},
{
"country_name":"Central African Republic",
"iso_code":"CF"
},
{
"country_name":"Albania",
"iso_code":"AL"
}
],
"hierarchy_information":{
"child_products":[
      ]
   }
}

'''Need a PLSQL procedure to parse the json response into tabledata
Oracle version 19.0'''

What have you tried ? Where did you get stuck ? You need the native function JSON_VALUE that is pretty well documented.

This should get you going
SQL> with t as
  2  ( select treat(
  3  '{
  4    "general": {
  5      "product_key": "136587",
  6      "group_subtype_id": 1,
  7      "group_subtype_name": "Wheel Speed Sensor",
  8      "variant_id": 2,
  9      "variant_name": "DF11",
 10      "rb_customer_id": 16732
 11    },
 12    "partnumbers": [
 13      {
 14        "partnumber": "0265009953",
 15        "pn_type": "Series OEM",
 16        "mat_status": "40 - Valid",
 17        "properties": [
 18          {
 19            "property_id": 4,
 20            "property_name": "ASIC P/N",
 21            "value_id": 27,
 22            "value": "8905509055"
 23          },
 24          {
 25            "property_id": 5,
 26            "property_name": "ASIC type",
 27            "value_id": 56,
 28            "value": "TLE4942"
 29          },
 30          {
 31            "property_id": 6,
 32            "property_name": "Axle",
 33            "value_id": 64,
 34            "value": "Front"
 35          }
 36        ]
 37      }
 38    ]
 39  }' as json) j from dual
 40  )
 41  select jt.*
 42  from t,
 43   json_table(j,'$.partnumbers[*]'
 44     columns (
 45       partnumber varchar2(20) path partnumber,
 46       pn_type varchar2(20) path pn_type ,
 47       nested path '$.properties[*]'
 48          columns(  property_id number path property_id
 49          )
 50       )
 51     ) jt;

PARTNUMBER           PN_TYPE              PROPERTY_ID
-------------------- -------------------- -----------
0265009953           Series OEM                     4
0265009953           Series OEM                     5
0265009953           Series OEM                     6


I tried this nested path, i need to retrieve all the info not only partnumbers. But for some reason i was able to retrive only the info under general . Could you please help me retrieve all info
